# Blockchain for business: platforms, use cases, adoption research papers and blockchain research paper/case studies hubs

Tags: blockchain

I am looking to conduct some research on the following topic:
**Blockchain for business: platforms, use cases, adoption.**
I would like to know where can I find research papers on this topic, whether peer-reviewed or not. An example paper of what I'm looking for is something like  [Hamida, E. B., Brousmiche, K. L., Levard, H., & Thea, E. (2017, July). Blockchain for enterprise: overview, opportunities and challenges.](https://www.thinkmind.org/articles/icwmc_2017_5_10_28001.pdf)
Any hubs which contain papers on such topics? Or in general research paper hubs which contain research on Blockchain, DeFi etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a big fan of Hyperledger.  The organization site blog has many adoption cases:  https://www.hyperledger.org/news/blog.  A very compelling business case can be found on Hyperledger - Iroha https://www.hyperledger.org/category/hyperledger-iroha
The National Bank of Cambodia has approx. 17 million consumers on "Bakong" - a Iroha DeFi blockchain.